# Execute JS code after the photo has started downloading with ht

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas, onrender

I am using html2canvas and Canvas2Image in order to get a screenshot of a map on my screen.
The functionality is running on a button click like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#screenshot2").click(function(){
    html2canvas($("#OpenLayers_Map_15_OpenLayers_ViewPort"), {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            // Convert and downloadimg-out as image
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
        }
    });
  });
  });
```

What I want is to have a loading sign while the process is running. It's easy to initiate the "loading image" on button click, but I haven't figured out how to stop it. For example, in Ajax, there are the `beforeSend` and `afterSend`. Is there something equivalent in this case?

Comment: You already know about the `onrendered` event, and how to attach an event handler. So is there some other event you need to wait for?

Comment: Well I need to stop the rotating icon for "loading" once the download of the photo starts. What event could I use for this?

Comment: html2canvas() almost undoubtedly uses jQuery.ajax() internally so you might take a look at "Global Ajax Event Handlers", however you might be snookered by the request being cross-domain.